# How to override the CellStyle value in excel dart package?

Tags: android, excel, flutter, dart

I am using excel dart package to create and edit excel files. 
I am trying to make my excel file look attractive by giving colors to excel cells.
I read the documentation [here](https://pub.dev/packages/excel#cell-style-options) and tried to do like this :

```
CellStyle color1 = CellStyle(
    fontColorHex: "#Ffffff",
    backgroundColorHex: "#80ff00",
    fontFamily: getFontFamily(FontFamily.Calibri),
  );
CellStyle color2 = CellStyle(
    fontColorHex: "#Ffffff",
    backgroundColorHex: "#Ea4a73",
    fontFamily: getFontFamily(FontFamily.Calibri),
  );
var cell = sheetObject.cell(CellIndex.indexByString("A1"));

//changing cell style to color 1
cell.CellStyle = color1;

//now again changing cell style to color 2
cell.CellStyle = color2;
```

**Problem with this:**
When I try to change the cellStyle to **color2** it persist the old values of **color1**. Why this is happening and how can I fix this, Is there any property to remove the cellStyle first and then assigning to new CellStyle. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue I found was that `cell.CellStyle` should be `cell.cellStyle`. if that was a mistake while adding code here, Then for your information, the current code works for me without any issue. try to delete the excel file been exported and clean the project and run the code again.

[image]